# Running total for current period when previous period is empty

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I could use a little SQL help this morning
I am new to SQL and could use some help.

I have a stored proc set up in SSMS whose purpose is to determine the quarter to date total of transactions for a service.

It looks at the transactions for the last transaction of the previous quarter. For example 6/30/2020. Finding that, it starts totaling transactions for the quarter. We call the transactions "matches".

So far so good. But I found a bug. We often have new accounts or dormant accounts that did not transact in the previous quarter at all and only started transacting in the current quarter.

So when the stored proc goes looking for the last transaction in the previous quarter and does not find one, i get anomalous results.

What I am guessing that I need to do is to set up the query so that if it does not find a transaction for the previous quarter that it defaults to zero so the rest of the stores proc can run.

But I am not sure of how to do that or if this is the best way to do it.

Following is my code so you can see where I am starting. Please take a look and I will greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to proceed.

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_add_QTD_ICSMatch]    Script Date: 7/13/2020 9:20:03 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_add_QTD_ICSMatch] 
AS
BEGIN

    --Alter Table [src].[ICSMatch]
    --Add ICSQTDOutstanding decimal (18,2) null
    --Alter Table [STG_ICSMatch]
    --Add ICSQTDOutstanding decimal (18,2) null

DECLARE @lastQuaterEnd date,
        @maxmatchdate date,
        @lastQuarterOutstanding decimal(18,2),
        @MaxMatchOutstanding decimal(18,2)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#QTD', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #QTD;
CREATE TABLE #QTD (Tranid varchar(18),
                    Qtd decimal(18,2),
                    BankID int,
                    Matchdate date,
                    LastQuaterDate date
                    )

SET @maxmatchdate  = (SELECT max(Match_date)  FROM  [src].[ICSMatch])

SET @lastQuaterEnd = (SELECT DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, @maxmatchdate), 0)) )-- Last day of last quarter
--Print @lastQuaterEnd

SET @lastQuaterEnd = (SELECT dbo.svf_getValidMatchDate(@lastQuaterEnd , 'ICS') )

--Print @lastQuaterEnd

;WITH lastQuarter as 
    (SELECT  ICSMatch.ICSOutstanding , ICSMatch.BANK_ID ,ICSMatch.Match_date
    FROM  [src].[ICSMatch]
    WHERE ICSMatch.Match_date = @lastQuaterEnd
    ),
    ThisMatch AS 
    (
    SELECT  ICSMatch.ICSOutstanding , ICSMatch.BANK_ID , ICSMatch.ICSTRAN_ID , ICSMatch.Match_date
    FROM  [src].[ICSMatch]
    WHERE ICSMatch.Match_date = @maxmatchdate
    )
    INSERT INTO #QTD 
    SELECT  t.ICSTRAN_ID , (t.ICSOutstanding - l.ICSOutstanding) AS qtd , t.BANK_ID , t.Match_date , l.Match_date FROM 
    ThisMatch t 
    left join lastQuarter l on l.BANK_ID = t.BANK_ID
    --where l.ICSOutstanding is not null
        
    UPDATE  ics
    SET ics.ICSQTDOutstanding = q.Qtd 
    FROM src.ICSMatch ics
    left join #QTD q ON ics.ICSTRAN_ID = q.Tranid
    WHERE ics.Match_date = @maxmatchdate

END
```

Thanks much for any help.
Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly this should take you part of the way, you might need to adjust the match_date too

```
INSERT INTO #QTD 
SELECT  
  t.ICSTRAN_ID , 
  (t.ICSOutstanding - IsNull(l.ICSOutstanding,0)) AS qtd , 
  t.BANK_ID , 
  t.Match_date , 
  l.Match_date 
FROM 
ThisMatch t 
left join lastQuarter l on l.BANK_ID = t.BANK_ID
```

Comment: Can you clarify for me what this does exactly? your change is to change this:"(t.ICSOutstanding - IsNull(l.ICSOutstanding,0)) AS qtd , " to this "(t.ICSOutstanding - l.ICSOutstanding) AS qtd , ". Like I said, I am new to this but it looks as if we are telling it to just do the same thing if the ICSTRAN_ID is NULL or NOT NULL. IF that is the case how do we populate the table where no prior transaction exists to pull that data from? I knew that this would have to include a path from if the ID is NULL but the process wants "Last Quarter" values. But in these cases there is no "Last Quarter".

Comment: So you are using a LEFT OUTER JOIN to the LastQuarter data and if there isn't a matching row it will come back NULL (that´s how left outer join works - right). My addition to your code replaces the NULL value with zero - which is what you described in your text, I haven't tested it as I don't have your data.

Comment: OK, so this change is just replacing a NULL for the l.ICSOutstanding with a zero correct? I just didn't think it would be that simple. I do have a question though at the top of the code, this section: IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#QTD', 'U') IS NOT NULL, what if it is? if there were no previous transactions, wouldn't it be NULL? That is what I was kind of hung up on.

Comment: IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#QTD', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #QTD;

If the table already exists drop it as your create will fail if there is already a table with this name (on this session_id - temporary tables are session specific).